# Wordpress clear cache / cookie Homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, caching, cookies

I had used WP Super Cache plugin and deleted and uninstalled it as it was caching my homepage. Even after deleting the plugin my homepage still shows cached.

When I do a http header check, it gives below response. I have not set this cookie but it shows expiry as 1 year from now. I have tried everything possible to delete / refresh / revalidate cache but was unsuccessful.

```
**Set-Cookie:** visid_incap_989857=oC6pZWXUTjiU7YzbsTt0rfNwPlgAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABpH3oz45/FNmoUvzKsMzun; expires=Wed, 29 Nov 2017 14:16:30 GMT; path=/; Domain=.hashtadonline.com   

**Set-Cookie:** incap_ses_501_989857=xeiQT4rd9CWgHXkh6+jzBvNwPlgAAAAAOOzFnVHy/vvIPuSGHx28MQ==; path=/; Domain=.hashtadonline.com
```

Can someone please suggest how to unset this cookie.